# pytest: monkeypatch while using hypothesis

Tags: pytest, monkeypatching, hypothesis-test, python-hypothesis

Within a unit test, I'm using `monkeypatch` in order to change entries in a `dict`.

```py
from hypothesis import given, strategies
    
    
test_dict = {"first": "text1", "second": "text2"}
    
    
given(val=strategies.text())
def test_monkeypath(monkeypatch, val):
    monkeypatch.setitem(test_dict, "second", val)
    
    assert isinstance(test_dict["second"], str)
```

The test passes, but I get a warning when executing the following test code with `pytest`.

```
=================================================================================================================== warnings summary ====================================================================================================================
.PyCharm2019.2/config/scratches/hypothesis_monkeypatch.py::test_monkeypath
  c:\users\d292498\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\pybt\lib\site-packages\hypothesis\extra\pytestplugin.py:172: HypothesisDeprecationWarning: .PyCharm2019.2/config/scratches/hypothesis_monkeypatch.py::test_monkeypath uses the 'monkeypatch' fixture, wh
ich is reset between function calls but not between test cases generated by `@given(...)`.  You can change it to a module- or session-scoped fixture if it is safe to reuse; if not we recommend using a context manager inside your test function.  See h
ttps://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#sharing-test-data for details on fixture scope.
    note_deprecation(

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
============================================================================================================= 1 passed, 1 warning in 0.30s ==============================================================================================================
```

Does this mean that the value of the dict will only be changed once, no matter how many test cases will be generated by `hypothesis`?
I am not sure how to use a context manager in this case. Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that the dict is patched only once for all test invocations, and Hypothesis is warning you about that.  If you had any logic before the `monkeypatch.setitem` line, this would be very bad!

You can work around this by [using monkeypatch directly](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch), instead of via a fixture:

```py
from hypothesis import given, strategies
from _pytest.monkeypatch import MonkeyPatch


test_dict = {"first": "text1", "second": "text2"}


@given(val=strategies.text())
def test_monkeypath(val):
    assert test_dict["second"] == "text2"  # this would fail in your version

    with MonkeyPatch().context() as mp:
        mp.setitem(test_dict, "second", val)
        assert test_dict["second"] == val

    assert test_dict["second"] == "text2"
```

*et voila*, no warning.

Comment: Your exact code is not working on my machine. I do get an `AttributeError: __enter__` in line 12. Can you please verify?

Comment: Typo, sorry - should have been `with MonkeyPatch().context() as mp:`

Answer (score 5):

Use the [monkeypatch context manager](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch.context)

```py
@given(val=strategies.text())
def test_monkeypath(monkeypatch, val):
    with monkeypatch.context() as m:
        m.setitem(test_dict, "second", val)

        assert isinstance(test_dict["second"], str)
```

Comment: The code is working, however, the warning doesn't disappear. Why is that? Can I be sure to ignore this warning?